# Echoing pice of html including vue.js directive with php?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

Is there a way to echoing a piece of html code from server including a vue.js directive ?

For example :

```
$a = "<a href="javascript:;" id="removeMagazin" value="'.$v['id'].'" class="fa  fa-remove" v-on:click="removeMagazine()"></a>";
echo json_encode($a);
```

Comment: If you want to do it that way, then I think you should just remove the `json_encode` and just echo the html directly :)